# Band Edge Filters

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, digital-filters

I am interested in using Band Edge Filters to do carrier frequency recovery but this is kind of secondary to my question which is:

How do you build an FIR filter which isn't symmetric about the negative frequency axis?

From what I remember basic FIR filter design enforced conditions resulting in the filters always being symmetric.

Comment: You remembering that is wrong. For example: take any symmetric FIR. Multiply point-wise with $e^{j\alpha n}, n=1,2,\ldots$. Almost all $\alpha$ will lead to non-symmetrical filters.

Comment: I just reviewed the basic way to approximate filters using the L2 norm so I understand how to generate them(but they will be complex).

Comment: By the way, what is the frequency shift property of the dft and can this be used to shift a filters frequency response? I know how multiplying by a complex exponential shifts the spectrum by the frequency coefficient in continuous time domain.

Comment: yeah, so that's exactly it. Nothing more to it.

Comment: Ok cool, do you have an intuitive explanation of the negative spectrum? Like what actually gets spit out of a filter which remove the positive spectrum of a signal?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: Basically, what does the negative spectrum of a signal look like by itself?

Comment: that is impossible to answer, since the negative spectrum carries as much info as the positive half, i.e. is completely defined by your signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller , i am not sure, but i think maybe the question is about building an FIR filter with complex coefficients.  where the imaginary part of the impulse response is the Hilbert transform of the real part.